# How do I retry the whole spec instead of individual specs in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

there is an option to use in cypress.json called "retries" that defines the number of times a failed test will be retried.

The way I have written my tests there is some relation between the tests
(test1 : create entry and get id, test2: get entry by id and edit it, test3: delete by id ) and most times the retries do not help me avoid flakiness and all the retries fail.

I can use the retry option in my CI/CD that will retry all the specs. which is too wasteful and not super helpful as I might get a flaky error in some other test in the second retry.

So ideally, I would like to retry the whole spec when it fails, is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

even if configured in describe at the top of the spec, retries are still per test:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this article](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/12/03/retry-rerun-repeat#repeat) the repeat option seems to achieve what you are looking for.
Nevertheless, as far as I understand it will repeat the whole cypress run command, not individual specs... I have not found any solution yet to run individual specs on failure.

```
$ npm i -D cypress-repeat
$ npx cypress-repeat run -n 5 --until-passes --record ...
```

Answer (score -4):

You shouldn't make your test dependent, have a look on the the [cypress best practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Having-tests-rely-on-the-state-of-previous-tests), but if you really have no other way look at [retries guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries.html#Custom-Configurations), you can use the retries on the `describe`:

```
describe('User bank accounts', {
  retries: 2
}, () => {
...
```

Comment: I remember seeing this in the docs but I wanted to try it out before commenting ... your suggestion just configures no of retries each test gets on this spec.. will add a screenshot in the description to make it clear